# Jquery function returning true and false when using each

Tags: javascript, jquery

Jquery function is returning true and false. I think the problem might rise from my each loop.

```
function myfunction(param){
    $.each(param, function(i, item){
        if(condition) return false;
    });
}

$.when(myfunction(param)).then(function(){
    console.log('true');
}, function(){
    console.log('false');
});
```

This then my function returns true and false so i could not resolve when.
How to make the function to return false on condition.

My actual code

```
function checkName(nameValue){
    var currlist = $( ".sortable-fields."+formType).find('li.sortable-field');
    var result = true;
    $.each(currlist, function(i, item){
        var elem = $(item);
        var data = elem.data('fieldData');
        if(data['name'] == nameValue) {
            result = false;
            return false;
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Nothing in code shown would indicate need to use `$.when`

Comment: `myfunction(param)` does not return a `Deffered Object`, it's clear that the `done` (first) function will always be invoked.

Comment: i tried $.Deferred but still the same.

Comment: Is there any asynchronous code used inside the loop? This is your second `$.when` question but so far you haven't shown what exactly you are trying to do by using it, or why you are needing it. Will get better help by providing higher level overview of your needs

Comment: @charlietfl I have added my function in my question. I will call an ajax if this function returns true otherwise I should not call ajax. How to do it? Is using $.when wrong?

Comment: Yes it's wrong, just return the results of the function, no need for `$.when` since there is nothing in your function related to promises or asynchronous operations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Returning within the `each` callback has a different connotation than returning a result from a function. Use a variable to return after the each is done iterating

```
function myfunction(param){
    var result = true;
    $.each(param, function(i, item){
        if(condition){
            result = false;
            return false;
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

Returning `false` within `each` itself just signals a stop to the iterations.